Create Procedural Material Following the Normal


Hi everyone, so i need to create procedural material that look's like the picture above, i've already create the 3D object, just need to create the material.
Already tried wave texture but it don't follow the curvature of the object, am i missing something?

Hard to tell when you don't give us any information on what the geometry of the obect is and how you have set up the material. When this is a Bézier curve with some profile sweeping along, you should use the UV output of a Texture Coordinate node, plug it into the Vector input of a Wave Texture node and set the Bands direction to Y. bands changing scale
